# How do I find out if a variable is a letter in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

Simple question, simple answer for someone who actually uses scheme. How can I find out if a variable is a letter of the alphabet?

I assumed it was something like this (letter? x) where x is some indefinate type. Can anyone tell me what boolean function could be used?

edit:

How could I make something that looks like this: (somFunction-isALetter? a)
Return: #t

Where a is not a variable.

Comment: I think you mean "value" instead of "variable" here; you're concerned with what value `x` contains, not the fact that it's called `x`.

Comment: @PaulStansifer true enough. Also though I know that 'letter?' is not the correct term, thus just an example.

Comment: I'm still not sure I know what you want. It could be two things: 1) Is the value that a given variable is bound to a string of length 1 where the single character in that string is a letter of the alphabet? 2) Is the string form of the symbol that represents a variable a string of length 1 where the single character in that string is a letter of the alphabet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Racket, the [`char-alphabetic?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html?q=letter?#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._char-alphabetic~3f%29%29) function only takes characters as arguments, but it's easy to define a function that returns false for all non-characters instead of failing:

```
(define (letter? x) (and (char? x) (char-alphabetic? x)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `char-alphabetic?` procedure for this. From the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html?q=letter?#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._char-alphabetic~3f%29%29):

> `char-alphabetic?` returns #t if char has the Unicode “Alphabetic” property.

Use it like this:

```
(char-alphabetic? #\a)
> #t
```

If the character is in a variable:

```
(define x #\a)
(char-alphabetic? x)
#t
```

Notice that `char-alphabetic?` only works for *characters*.

**UPDATE:**

Re-reading the question I believe I misunderstood it. If you're interested in finding out if a *variable* 's name is just a single letter, this will work:

```
(define (is-variable-a-letter? x)
  (let ((var (string->list (symbol->string x))))
    (and (= (length var) 1)
         (char-alphabetic? (car var)))))

(is-variable-a-letter? 'x)
> #t
```

On the other hand, if you're interested in the actual *contents* of the variable, then apply the first part of this answer.